# What web browsers support ECC vs DSA vs RSA for SSL/TLS?

Tags: encryption, tls, web-browser, webserver, wildcard

We are updating our wildcard certificate and see that we have the option to use both RSA or DSA with Symantec (for [free](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/introducing-algorithm-agility-ecc-and-dsa)), while [Digicert](https://www.digicert.com/ecc.htm) offers 3 options for wildcards ECC, DSA and RSA.

Is there a compatibility matrix for which browsers support ECC? (or the others)

We only support TLS1 and newer, so this may make ECC support easier

**Related:**

Based on my research, Network Solutions, and GoDaddy only offer RSA.  No DSA or ECC support.  Comodo supports ECDSA curves secp521r1 secp384r1 prime256v1

Symantec Wildcards don't support certificate transparency at this time

Comment: I think [Qualys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html) has got the information you need. Click on the clients name to get detailed information about what is supported by this client.

Answer (score 4):

According to [GlobalSign](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1995283-ecc-compatibility), the following browsers support ECC:

```
Browser                         Minimum Version Required

Apple Safari                    4 (On ECC Compatible OS)
Google Chrome                   1.0 (On ECC Compatible OS)
Microsoft Internet Explorer     7 (On ECC Compatible OS)
Mozilla Firefox                 2.0
```

Supported operating systems are:

```
Operating System            Minimum Version Required

Apple OS X                  OS X 10.6
Google Android              4.0
Microsoft Windows           Windows Vista
Red Hat Enterprise Linux    6.5
```